# How to write functor that is constructible from lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda, std-function

When I convert a lambda to an std::function object, it gets converted and in case less than 24 bytes are captured (e.g. this pointer), std::function doesn't issue a heap alloc.

Now my question is how can I construct my own functor from a lambda and extract this-ptr from the lambda to save it in my functors memory layout?

Comment: You can't, at least not in any way that's specified in the C++ standard. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: Lambdas are functor objects already. I don't see how you could do better then that. Maybe you need to explain a bit more about what you are doing (and why)

Comment: A lambda is a functor.  A lambda does not have it's own `this` pointer.  A lambda can **capture** a `this` pointer.

Comment: " in case less than 24 bytes are captured [...], std::function doesn't issue a heap alloc." Seems like you refer to some specific implementation. You can look at that implementatiom to see how it is realized

Comment: What would, if lambdas exposed their own `this` pointer, this one contain then? The address in memory of the lambda! This one you can get easily via a template, see the example at [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rfexvc38P) – though you don't need that template for at all, see last line before returning from `main`. Question, though, is: What would you want to do with that address anyway? Likely we're talking about an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here...

Comment: @PepijnKramer I need to type erase the lambda but not in the way std::function does. I want to put the captured data into a memory_resource. So basically I want to implement std::function but for pmr's.

Comment: Maybe this could be helpful? https://youtu.be/u5EAJTHPJN8 If you are impatient, skip to 33:19

Comment: If your question is how to implement your own version of [std::experimental::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/function), your question should say that. If that's not your question, you should edit it to be more clear, with an example of a piece of code you would like to be able to compile.